# How to customize the color of mapped variable in a geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-text

I want to customize the colors which map the `default_binary` variable in a `geom_text`. Tried using `scale_fill_manual` which works for a `geom_bar`, but nothing happens. Any ideas? Added the link for how it looks like rn in the end.[1]

```
ggplot(DATA) +
  geom_text(aes(x = recession_binary, y = percents, label = percents, color = default_binary)) +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = c("Default" = rgb(232/255,74/255,39/255), "Paid in full" = rgb(19/255,41/255,75/255)))
```

Put simply, I just want to substitute the pink and green with the blue and orange denoted by the rgb above (doesn't matter the order):
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxzsk.png

Comment: Try using `scale_color_manual`. The `scale_fill_manual` is intended to use when you have a `fill` in your `aes` statement. For future reference, when you seek help on this site you should include a sample of your data to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above by changing the `scale_color_manual` to `scale_color_manual` you will get the desired result. `geom_text` does not have a `fill` aesthetic.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
mpg %>% 
  filter(class %in% c('compact', 'minivan'), cyl %in% c(4, 6)) %>% 
  group_by(class, cyl) %>% 
  summarise(cty= mean(cty)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(class, cty, color=as_factor(cyl), label= cyl) ) +
  geom_text()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c(rgb(232/255,74/255,39/255), 
                                cty= rgb(19/255,41/255,75/255)))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'class' (override with `.groups` argument)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @VitorFernandes, if Evan M. answered your question sufficiently, please accept the answer by "checking" his answer.